# How to get s3 url in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I uploaded a file on s3. Now I want to get the s3 url of that file in Nodejs.
The url should have format "s3://Bucket-name/filename.txt"

i tried s3.getSignedUrl() but it returned a https url.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the s3.upload method just like this

```
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Body: stream};
var options = {partSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, queueSize: 1};
s3.upload(params, options, function(err, data) {
  console.log(err, data);
});
```

once you do that you can fetch the URL of the uploaded file by

```
`data.Location`
```

[Aws Docs for data.Location](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) ( check callback parameters )